# What is the technical term for a UI designed for experts?

Tags: user-experience

An example of this is the command line-based software that some airlines still use.  It takes forever to learn the UI (keyed in commands, keyboard shortcuts, etc.), but after the person learns it, it is more efficient to use than UIs designed for everyone (with lots of white space, etc.)

I was thinking this was called an Expert System, but this term is used for an AI-based systems.

Comment: Do you mean CLI (command line interface)?

Comment: Some of those airlines could be using SAA CUA terminal applications written by or for IBM platforms. A tell is if the application display a F key action map at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Command Line Interface**. Besides [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)'s definition and review on its history, you may also take a look at another source [here](https://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/definition/command-line-interface-CLI).